# Youtube api - Retrieve all tags in a channel

Tags: javascript, json, youtube-api

Is there a way to retrieve a json of all the tags used in a Youtube channel?

I'm trying to show all the videos of a channel on a website and I'd like to make a dropdown or something similar to filter the videos by tag.

If not possible directly, how can i parse the channel json to obtain a list of all the tags?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Ok, there's no way to retrieve it directly :(

I know I can get a json of the channel using the url http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/uploads?&v=2&alt=jsonc (this is the example for Google channel) and each item has its tags.

Which is the best way to obtain a list of all the tags in another json (or in an array) removing duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to get that information, I'm afraid. You'll first need to get [all videos uploaded to a channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#User_Uploaded_Videos), and then iterate through [each video to get the tags](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_entries).

Comment: Ok, I was afraid that there wasn't a direct way, I'll try iterating the channel json

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at API [here?](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_channel_search)  To get json data you would add &alt=json-in-script to end of request.  Eg.

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channels?q=soccer&v=2&alt=json-in-script
```

Comment: Yep, I've looked at API, but I was just wondering if there is a way to obtain directly a list of the tags used in a channel